# Unclosed GSP expression: Grails GSP engine does not resolve nested GSP expression

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I need to create a custom gsp whose domain model is designed as follows

```
class Question {

    SortedSet<Choice> choiceCollection;

    static hasMany = [choiceCollection:Choice]
    static mappping = {
        choiceCollection(joinTable:false)
    }

}
```

Each Question object has five Choices. So, i create the following snippet of code

**create.gsp**

```
<g:each var="i" in="${(1..5)}">
    <div class="fieldcontain  required">
    <label for="description">
            Option ${i}.
            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </label>
        <g:textArea name="choiceCollection[${i}].description" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="2000" value="${questionInstance?.choiceCollection[${i}]?.description}"/>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

Although Grails GSP engine complains *Unclosed GSP expression* which is not true - g:textArea is closed as you can see above -, i believe the real problem is the expression

```
${questionInstance?.choiceCollection[${i}]?.description}
```

which involves nested GSP expressions.

Question: am i missing some feature ? If so, what should i do to overcome my obstacle ?

Grails version: 2.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
${questionInstance?.choiceCollection[${i}]?.description}
```

be

```
${questionInstance?.choiceCollection[ i ]?.description}
```

---

The set bit:

Try something like:

```
<g:each var="choice" status="i" in="${questionInstance?.choiceCollection}">
```

So `i` still contains your index, but `choice` contains what you were trying to get with `questionInstance?.choiceCollection[${i}]`

Comment: Thanks (+1). Now, after initializing my SortedSet with a TreeSet, i get No signature of method: java.util.TreeSet.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) ? Do you know why ? What should i do to run my application ?

Comment: Yeah, you can't get positional elements out of a Set, even a SortedSet :-(  You probably want to go from the Set to a List, or keep the items in a List, and use `list.unique().sort()` to mimic the functionality you're getting from the `TreeSet`.  Or you can just use `each` to iterate the set rather than trying to use an integer index, ie: `([ 1, 2, 3 ] as TreeSet).each { println it }`

Comment: @ArthurRonaldFDGarcia Added a bit about replacing the `each`